# How can combine two strings completely or partially?

Tags: python

I need your help on improving my work on python. As below my starting point is a table with 2 columns "Name 1" and "Name 2".
What I need is an "Output" column which is the result of the combination, complete combination or partial, in order to have a unique string.
On Knime I've already built the solution but now I want to move it on python; on knime I've used a Python script node followed by Ungroup to have one result on each row.

**Python script on Knime**

```
from itertools import combinations

# Copy input to output
output_table_1 = input_table_1.copy()

for i, names in enumerate(input_table_1['Output']):
  #print(i, names)
  names_array = names.split(' ')
  output_table_1['Output'][i] = []
  for size in range(len(names_array) + 1):
    for combo in combinations(names_array, size):
      output_table_1['Output'][i].append(' '.join(combo))
```

**Starting table**

| ID | Name 1 | Name 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mario Rossi | Luigi Verdi |
| 2 | Antonio | Marco de Giusti |
| 3 | Fabio | Michele |
| 4 | Carlo Michele Stefano | Gino |

**Output table**

| ID | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mario - Luigi |
| 1 | Mario Rossi - Luigi |
| 1 | Mario - Luigi Verdi |
| 1 | Mario Rossi - Luigi Verdi |
| 1 | Rossi - Luigi |
| 1 | Rossi - Verdi |
| 1 | Rossi - Luigi Verdi |
| 2 | Antonio - Marco |
| 2 | Antonio - Marco de |
| 2 | Antonio - Marco de Giusti |
| 2 | Antonio - de |
| 2 | Antonio - Giusti |
| 2 | Antonio - de Giusti |
| 2 | Antonio - Marco Giusti |
| 3 | Fabio - Michele |
| 4 | Carlo - Gino |
| 4 | Michele - Gino |
| 4 | Stefano - Gino |
| 4 | Carlo Michele - Gino |
| 4 | Carlo Stefano - Gino |
| 4 | Michele Stefano - Gino |
| 4 | Carlo Michele Stefano - Gino |

Comment: What is the question? It sounds like you've already done what you want to do?

Comment: Hi Kendle, the code is written on a Knife code. I can't run it on python